# How do I convert a Text to a bytestring Builder?

Tags: haskell

The `blaze-builder` package provides a `.Char.Utf8` module which includes `fromText` and `fromLazyText` for efficiently converting a value from the text package into a `blaze-builder` `Builder` value. With the new Builder API in `bytestring`, however, no such function exists (since `bytestring` does not depend on `text`). We could unpack the `Text` values and use `stringUtf8`, but that's almost certain to be much slower.

Another option would be to use `blaze-builder`, which is now actually just a wrapper around `bytestring`'s `Builder` type, but I'm wondering if there's a more idiomatic way of approaching this.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's not even a wrapper around `bytestring`'s `Builder` type—it *is* `bytestring`'s `Builder` type!

Comment: Correct. I meant that the package itself is a wrapper, providing the legacy names for new functions.

Comment: And looking at [the source for blaze-builder](http://haddock.stackage.org/nightly-2015-09-20/blaze-builder-0.4.0.1/src/Blaze-ByteString-Builder-Char-Utf8.html#fromText), looks like an assumption on my part may have been wrong: it defines `fromText = fromString . unpack`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but probably you want [encodeUtf8Builder](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.1.3/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html#v:encodeUtf8Builder)?

Comment: What is wrong with Builder.byteString . Encoding.encodeUtf8  ?

Comment: @yuras that's the ticket. Could you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [encodeUtf8Builder](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.1.3/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html#v:encodeUtf8Builder) function and the corresponding function for [lazy text](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.1.3/docs/Data-Text-Lazy-Encoding.html#v:encodeUtf8Builder).